# Custom PC driver installation

Tags: windows, boot, drivers, oem

So I'm getting into selling custom computers running Windows 8.1. I want to have necessary drivers installed before the user boots into Windows for first setup (so after everything is installed and they get to the personalization screen) so that they don't have to do anything to get it working properly. I suppose what I'm asking, is how do computer manufacturers such as HP or Lenovo have drivers preinstalled? Also, I was reading somewhere about the registry for setting custom OEM values. I'd also like to make use of this as I plan on starting a business for this and think it would be more professional to show my logo and such where other manufacturers have theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They take a couple of different tactics.

The OEM will often create a custom disk image, with the drivers installed, and simply write their image to the disk drive.

Another approach is to use the [Unattended Setup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699026.aspx) features of the Windows installer to perform the driver installations at the end of the Windows install process.

Either approach requires knowledge of the hardware involved. I'm sure the big guys ship a library of drivers and have scripts that determine which package is right for each computer model or SKU number.

Click [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766485%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) for instructions on creating a Windows PE disk that installs drivers using an Answers file.

Comment: Very interesting. I googled a little bit about this before asking and didn't find anything like this. Should help out a lot, thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

They will use builds for each type of machine to mass produce the products, where each particular build has the required drivers and updates etc.